# Invoke initializer for swift class using type

Tags: swift

I have an array like such:

```
static var handlers: [MyProtocol.Type] = [Handler1.self, Handler2.self]
```

Handler 1, 2, etc.. are Objects that inherit from BaseHandler. Now Im having some trouble returning an instance of the object. For instance, i want to do this:

```
func getHandler(_ idx: Int) -> MyProtocol.Type? {
    let handler: BaseHandler.Type = handlers[0] as! BaseHandler.Type
    return handler()
}
```

I get a compiler error saying "cannot invoke 'handler' with no arguments". But BaseHandler has an init function without arguments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can just use `init`, but you probably want to formalize it in the protocol.

**Example**

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  init() 
  func f() -> Int 
} 

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol { 
  // This struct gets an automatic no-arg constructor
  func f() -> Int { return 12 } 
} 


let ps: [MyProtocol.Type] = [ MyStruct.self ]
ps[0].init().f() // 12
```

Comment: Looks like we need to now use .init() instead. Wonder what version of swift this got deprecated.